# ACF Flexible Content выдает лаги WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

есть ACF PRO , использую динамический контент ( flexible content )
Каждый item это лишь текстовые поля, но со времени их надбралось около 450) И сейчас в админке WordPress на странице где редактирвется это появились лаги. Оперативная память у администратора и редактора доходит до максимум вызывая слезы, Угнетение и суицидальные мысли. Кто с этим сталкивался, как можно расспределить их , ибо 450 пунктов очень много) и при добавлении нового лагает сильно

Comment: А вам не кажется, что 450 редактирующих пунктов это просто плохое решение?)

Comment: Пора что-то менять в консерватории.

Comment: В общем волшебной таблетки - нет. Либо увеличивайте лимиты на сервере. Либо сделайте теперь нормально)